# .htaccess 'IF' in rewrite rule?

Tags: .htaccess

This is my rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/.+)? /negocio$2.php?shopURL=$1 [L,QSA]
```

If `$2` doesn't exist (URL doesn't have two slashes), I want to echo '/' instead of '.php'. So the condition becomes:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/.+)? /negocio/?shopURL=$1 [L,QSA]
```

How do I do this or archive the same result?

Comment: you can do it using two rules or use rewritecond

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure this is what RewriteCond is for!

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)(/.+)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/.+)? /negocio$2.php?shopURL=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/([^/]+)$
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/.+)? /negocio/?shopURL=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I get redirected to a 404 page when using it. However both rules work fine separately so it has to do with the condition.

Comment: It seems no rules are applying. If I go to `/myshop/info` I get `/myshop/info` (not `negocio/info.php?shopURL=myshop`) the same happens with `/myshop`

Comment: Oh, %{REQUEST_URI} begins with a /, so you'll have to account for that in the regex. i edited the rules above.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your code with this:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ negocio/?shopURL=$1 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)(/.+?)/?$ negocio$2.php?shopURL=$1 [L,QSA]
```